# How to validate json file in C++?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Currently I have a JSON file (Test.json) with some valid data in json format and i'am trying to parse the data using a json object (readData) using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), as below

```
Json::Value readData;   
std::ifstream readFile("Test.json");  
readFile >> readData;
```

This works fine if the json file is having valid contents in json format, but it crashes at "readFile >> readData" if the contents are not of a json format.
is there any way to validate the file before assigning it to a json object in C++ ?

Comment: `std::ifstream readFile(Test.json);` won't compile. I believe you meant `std::ifstream readFile("Test.json");`.

Comment: If it crashes, my best bet is that unsuccessful reads raise an exception. Try to reach for the documentation for confirmation or wrap your `>> `in a `try`-`catch` block and try to catch the correct excetpion.

Comment: Are you using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) library?

Comment: @Fureeish Indeed, http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/namespace_json.html#a4d245ef719cc0853e8e78eb5f99c16e5 says "std::exception on parse error".

Comment: @Azeem yes i'am using jsoncpp library

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "crash"; [it throws an exception](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/namespace_json.html#a4d245ef719cc0853e8e78eb5f99c16e5). I'd guess you're not catching that exception.

Anyway, for reading JSON you probably want to use [`parseFromStream`](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/index.html#_advanced). This allows you to set options, and returns `true` or `false`. The `operator>>` you're using is just a shortcut.

Please read documentation for the functions that you use. It's there to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this code instead. It will not crash the program. It will just show you (on STDERR) what error has occurred.

```
Json::Value readData;   
std::ifstream readFile("Test.json");
if (readFile) {
    try {
        readFile >> readData; 
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
else {
    std::cerr << "File not found!" << std::endl;
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/namespace_json.html#a4d245ef719cc0853e8e78eb5f99c16e5) of JsonCpp, `operator>>()` results in `std::exception` on parse error.